# Group By in LINQ/List by single property of User Defined Object

Tags: vb.net, linq, list, group-by

I have searched the web and just can't grasp the group by using LINQ or just the group by on a list of objects. I need to group by a property on the objects inside a list so that it combines the quantities for each location(removing duplicate data).

Lets say the list object is this
    Property Site
    Property Quantity

And the list contains

```
Item(0).Site = 001
Item(0).Quantity = 100
Item(1).Site = 001
Item(1).Quantity = 200
Item(2).Site = 002
Item(2).Quantity = 100
Item(3).Site = 002
Item(3).Quantity = 200
```

I need to group by Site so that it ends up with this in the final list

```
Item(0).Site = 001
Item(0).Quantity = 300
Item(1).Site = 002
Item(1).Quantity = 300
```

Im using VB.Net and List(Of CustomDT) that indeed contains the above 2 properties as well as others.

Comment: Oh btw lets say the list is Dim results as list(of DT)

Answer (score 1):

It is not to hard if you understand how to group in SQL.  For me the best was to understand is by example. Below I just Dynamically create two people and put them into a collection. My result is to get a list of people grouped by the age.  So you have the KeySelector which is what you are using as your key for the GroupBy Operation, ElementSelector which is the IEnumerable(Of T) of what element you want to summaries and finally the record selector is used to combine the Key and the and the IEnumerable into a new value.  One think to keep in mind is when you use ValueObjects or Dynamic Objects as in this case you need to be sure you override GetHash and Equals To.  I have blogged about creating a comparer for ExpandoObject with links to GitHub for sample code incase you want to get this to work. If that was the case you would have to add a comparer after the RecordSelector.  I hope this helps.

http://wysnet.blogspot.com/2013/08/comparer-for-expandoobject.html?view=magazine.

```
    Dim person1 As Object = New Dynamic.ExpandoObject
    person1.Name = "John"
    person1.Age = 10


    Dim person2 As Object = New Dynamic.ExpandoObject
    person2.Name = "Jake"
    person2.Age = 10

    Dim people As New List(Of Object)
    people.AddRange({person1, person2})

    Dim personByAge = people.GroupBy(keySelector:=Function(i) i.Age,
                                     elementSelector:=Function(e) e.Name,
                                     resultSelector:=Function(k, e)
                                                         Dim groupbyItem As Object = New Dynamic.ExpandoObject
                                                         groupbyItem.Key = k
                                                         groupbyItem.People = New List(Of String)(e)
                                                         Return groupbyItem
                                                     End Function)
```

Comment: hmmm i'll have to get this method implemented and do some testing with it. I create my own custom objects so looks like i'll have to override those methods using the class you provided. Be nice if microsoft included this type of capabilities out of the box : / I'll post up how it goes.

Comment: If you need any help just let me know. The best way would be to share using github if you are interested.